# How to pass a jtable variable to a controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to use jquery-jtabel in CodeIgniter but I'm having problems passing variable `bulantahun` from view/ajax to controller. This is my code.

```
//this is the ajax code 
$('#TableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Absensi',
                paging: true,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'bulanTahun ASC',
                selecting: true,
                multiselect: true, 
                selectingCheckboxes: true, 


                actions: {
                    listAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/listRecord',
                    createAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/create',
                    updateAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/update',
                    deleteAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/delete'
                },
// the field is here


$('#TableContainer').jtable('load',{
                    bulantahun:$("#from").val()
            });


//and this is my code in Controller
function create()
{
$bulantahun = $this->input->post('bulantahun'); //failed to post this value
//my code here
}
```

Comment: Try this send data in get like createAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/create&id='bulantahun'

Comment: and how I get the value in Controller?
$this->input->get('bulantahun'), doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't post from ajax. So I think that's your problem. You'll need to do something like this in you jquery function:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Absensi_controller/create",
      data: bulantahun,
      success: success,
      dataType: String
    )};
```

Comment: so I can't use jtable in CodeIgniter? I use jtable before without framework, and it is success to post from ajax/jtable to php.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just did a little investigation about his.
You should create a controller with the following functions (You've allready done one :-)

```
    function listRecord(){

    }

    function create(){

    }  

    function update(){

    }

    function delete(){

    }
```

Then in the javascipt part:

```
    var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>"; // this line is the one that was missing in your code
    actions: {
                listAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/listRecord',
                createAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/create',
                updateAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/update',
                deleteAction: base_url+'Absensi_controller/delete'
            }
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry because I don't publish my code completely here. I was writing my code like your suggestion, and I say thanks. But my problem is I can't get the value of bulantahun in Controller. I'm trying
$this->input->post('bulantahun'), 
 but I can't get the value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, have you've tried to var_dump the post array ? Something like this:

```
    function create()
    {
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try. Check if the url is correct that you've contructed in javascript.

do something like this: alert(base_url+'Absensi_controller/create');

Also check if you can access the url in your browser. Create an echo 'Some text'; to make sure....

Comment: I have check it like this code:

function create()
{
$bulantahun=$this->input->post('bulantahun');
if($bulantahun != null) echo "success";
else echo "error";
}

and the result is error

Comment: Did you try what I've suggested? Because if the url (in the javascript part) is wrong itwon't work

Comment: Thanks. I've getting the solution. It is not because the url, but in controller, I forgot to write "exit();" after echoing json_encode. here my code:
function listRecord()
{
$this->load->model('model_superadmin');
$jTableResult=$this->model_superadmin->list_record();
print_r(json_encode($jTableResult));
exit();
}

Answer (score 0):

I've getting the solution. My fault, I'm no writing exit() function after echoing json. Here my code at controller

```
function listRecort()
{
$this->load->model('model_superadmin');
$jtableResult = $this->model_superadmin->listRecord();
echo json_encode($jtableResult):
exit(); //I miss this function
}
```